# Pandas - Filter Out Based On Multiple Criteria, One Column Contains Duplicates

Tags: python, pandas

Having trouble with a few errors. I'm trying to filter out data if two conditions are met.

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd
import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

effdate = datetime.date(2018,12,31)
conn = pyodbc.connect(
    r'DRIVER={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};'
    r'SERVER=server;'
    r'DATABASE=database;'
    r'Trusted_Connection=yes;'
    )
strSQL = "" # here is a SQL query which pulls many columns, including SaleDate, which is date format, and CategoryName, which contains text

df_auction = pd.read_sql(strSQL, conn)
priordate_rt = effdate + relativedelta(months=-6)
priordate_rt = pd.Timestamp(priordate_rt)
df_auction['SaleDateAdj'] = pd.to_datetime(df_auction['SaleDate'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
df_auction = df_auction[~((df_auction['CategoryName']=='Cars') & (df_auction['SaleDateAdj']<priordate_rt))]
```

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

I can tell you that this works by itself:

```
df_test = df_auction[(df_auction['SaleDateAdj']<priordate_rt)]
```

This line by itself gives me ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis.

```
df_test = df_auction[(df_auction['CategoryName']=='Cars')]
```

Comment: Figured it out. I had more than one column in my df called CategoryName. Once I remove the duplicate, the code above works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing

```
import pandas as pd
df_test['SaleDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df_test['SaleDate'])
```

And then performing the comparisson to filter out.

Comment: It worked! I tried a lot of things including converting the column to datetime like your suggestion, but maybe at that time I had converted the variable priordate_rt to string. Thank you!

Comment: Glad I could help, if you know the format of your dates in that column, you should pass them to the `.to_datetime` method for faster results

Comment: Sorry Diego, one more question. I was working on df_test and it works. df_test = df_auction earlier in the code. But when I do the same to_datetime on df_auction, the filtering doesn't work. TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'. Do you have any insight there?

Comment: @maxutil not sure what you mean. Could you update your question including the code for `df_auction`